# jquery spinning circle until load() function is finished

Tags: jquery, loading

On the index.php page of my site, I have a list of filter option that a user can click on to narrow down the results. Upon click of one of the

tags, jquery will populate the contents of the div with what is generated in another file called index_backend.php.

My code is as follows

```
$("#scores").click(function() {
    var url = 'index_backend.php';
    var data = 'type=scores';

    $('#center').load(url, data);
});
```

However, depending on what the value of the $_GET['type'] variable is in the url, loading the index_backend.php file can take a long time. Is there any way to find out when the file is finished loading completely? I tried putting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".loading").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

in the index_backend.php file, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ It has a 'completed' callback which is executed when the server responds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#center').load(url, data, function() {
  $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You can even go a bit wilder by adding an error handler too, to detect whether the page loaded successfully:

```
$("#center").load(url, data, 
    function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
          alert("Oh bother!!!!");
        } else {
          $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
        }
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can get good loading icons [here](http://ajaxload.info/).

To use, create an image element:

```
<a class="loading" href="loading.gif" style="display:none">
```

and this'll be your JS:

```
$("#scores").click(function() {
    $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');
    var url = 'index_backend.php';
    var data = 'type=scores';
    $('#center').load(url, data, function() {
      $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I use the jquery load function all the time but had never used the callback. Kind of a silly question now that I know the answer is that simple. Do you know how to generate a spinning circle while the page is still loading?

Comment: Thanks. All of that helps. But, I downloaded an image from that site that you gave me a link to and put it in my img folder. But, it's not appearing.

Comment: @Lance: Its not appearing on your computer or your webpage?

Comment: Nvm. I got it. Thanks a bunch. This feature really adds a level of class and sophistication to the look and feel of my site.

Comment: @Lance: I love spinning things too :)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the api http://api.jquery.com/load/ use the complete callback.

```
$('#center').load(url, data, function() {
    // load complete
});
```